# cakephp post switching to put

Tags: cakephp, post, put

I'm using cakephp, and I've run into a very strange thing. My form is setup to use a post method, but is using put automatically. Has anyone else come across this? How do I fix this? Why is this happening?

Comment: Show us your top secret view and controller action code please :D

Comment: See http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2528-request-type-put-instead-of-post or the documentation. Let me guess: You also got an "add" form there, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the inclusion or omission of the current records id field. If you include an id the form automatically becomes and 'edit', without an id it will be a 'create'